# How do to use Pinia getters in Vue template?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, pinia

How do I use Pinia getters defined in my store in my component templates?
With Vuex, I can do `this.$store.getters.getterName(params)`.
Here is my attempt using Pinia.

```
<script lang="ts">
import { useStore } from "@/store/store";

export default {
  setup() {
    const store = useStore;

    return {
      store,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<template>
<h1>{{ store.getterName(params) }}</h1>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `useStore` inside `setup`.

```
export default {
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();

    return {
      store,
    };
  },
};
```